# Why don't date selections via the pop-up stick when adding an event?

Tags: civievent

On events, manage events, add event, on the start date, even though you select a new date from the pop up calendar, the date doesn't change from the current date. This seems to be the same issue with the End date and sometimes when you select the month, the calendar automatically changes the year to 1995 if you key in the date manually, it works.

I am using CiviCRM version 4.5.5 and i have also tested on the demo site currently running 4.5.9 on firefox 39.0 and chrome Version 44.0.2403.107 m

I can file an issue if any other person can confirm this

Answer (score 1):

Changing the month and year in the calendar doesn't have any effect until you click on a date. This can be a little confusing - is that your issue? This UX never seemed quite right to me but it's jQuery UI's thing, not ours.

Comment: Hi Coleman, this works correctly in CiviCRM 4.6.6, when tested earlier in version 4.5.9, the issue is that when you select a month, the year skips back to 1995 and even if you pick a date from the calendar, it doesn't save it ,this is also the case with 4.5.5